# Tricks for speeding up Conjugate Gradient on Normal Equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, least-squares

I have been using Krylov subspace methods for a long time in my research.

I know from general theory of Krylov subspace methods that for solving a problem:

$$\bf Ax = b$$

if $\bf A$ is square and positive definite for example symmetric, then we can get away with $\dim({\bf x})$ iterations of Conjugate Gradient (C-G).

For a particular problem I am solving recently, because of lack of mentioned properties for $\bf A$ I build the following Normal-equations:

$${\bf A}^T{\bf Ax = A}^T {\bf b}$$

Where we will be sure that $({\bf A}^T{\bf A})$ will be positive semi definite. Maybe for stability we can add Tykhonov regularizing term : $+\lambda \bf I$:

$$({\bf A}^T{\bf A}+\lambda{\bf I}){\bf x} = {\bf A}^T {\bf b}$$

Then it seems I get good solution only for iteration count of $\geq 2\dim({\bf x})$.

My questions are two-fold:

1. Can we prove this, and
2. Does there exist any methods to avoid this doubling in number of iterations?

---

My own work is mostly restricted to speculation about some clever choosing of $\lambda$ for regularization or perhaps if we can find some suitable preconditioner?

Comment: @mathreader I'm guessing that a preconditioner might do the trick... Relating the condition number  of $A^T A$ with the one of $A$ gives some idea of what may happen if $k(A)$ isn't small.

Comment: @PierreCarre yep, I suspect condition number might be quite nasty for my $\bf A$s. The matrix generation is data driven, so something as simple as better normalization of data maybe helps.

Comment: Generally you just shouldn't use the normal equations period. You're forcing yourself to do more preconditioning than the underlying problem really needs.

Comment: @Ian from one perspective you are right. From another perspective I don't agree. For any little expansion we want to make on our problem solving ability with our method, add a small cost term here, encourage another type of behavior over there, et.c. we will quite soon need to be able to do some norm minimization anyways. It can be worth a lot to not have to rewrite the whole algorithm just because it does not fulfill same strict constraints as before.

Comment: I'm not following. What problem is forcing the normal equations on you? If your problem boils down to minimizing $\| Ax-b \|$ then there are superior methods to the normal equations.

Comment: Yes, but not as soon as we realize we would like to add terms like $+\|Cx-d\|$ and also expand the space and solve for more variables simultaneously.